# How to add Android Dependencies Jar to Titanium Module

Tags: titanium-modules, titanium-android

Titanium module is not an Android project, there is no Android Dependencies.

How can I add a jar which has to be added to Android Dependencies.
I tries to add it to the Referenced Libraries but the sdk cannot be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can move any `*.jar` files to `android/lib` directory and any binary `*.so` to `android/libs` directory. Libs will be include in the final module distribution.

Comment: I have added it to the android/lib folder, but it cannot be referred. It will be added to Referenced library folder but not the Android Dependencies folder.

Comment: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Project-section-43289002_AndroidModuleProject-ProjectStructure
What does mean "but it cannot be referred"? Please provide build log with error.

Comment: Thanks. When I added the jar to the android/lib, the class in the jar cannot be referred, no class found error.